# how to hook the windows xp application using SetWindowHookEx()

Tags: visual-c++

Using win32 API and Dynamic link library(dll) where to write the callback function in my console application or anywhere else

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs .

Kimmi

Comment: I have successfully hook keyboard through keyboardproc callback function in mydll thanks kimmi